# An application of Young's inequality and without it.

Tags: calculus, inequality, logarithms, exponential-function

My maths ninja skills have gone kaput.

I tried hard to prove that:

> For $a> 0$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}$ we get from Young's inequality that: $(ab) \le a\log a - a +e^b$ or by other approach.

I tried using the exponential interpolation lemma that is used to prove Young's Lemma, i.e for $t\in [0,1]$ $e^{ta+(1-t)b}\le te^a + (1-t)e^b$, where I take $t=1/2$ and $1/2(a+b)=\log(uv)$ and $1/2 e^a = u\log u -u , e^v=1/2 e^b$; but it didn't help here.

Also tried by approaching directly by Young's inequality, but didn't succeed.

Should be easy, right?

Comment: that is the generalized Yound inequality involving the Lehendre Transform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(The easy way.)
For every $a > 0$, by a direct computation you get
$$
ab - e^b \leq \sup_{b\in\mathbb{R}} (ab - e^b) = a\log a - a,
$$
and you are done.

Explanation with the Fenchel-Legendre transform.
Let $\varphi(b) := e^b$, and compute
$$
\varphi^*(a) := \sup_{b\in\mathbb{R}} [ab - \varphi(b)],
\qquad a > 0.
$$
It is easily seen that the $\sup$ is achieved at $b = \log a$, hence
$$
\varphi^*(a) = a \log a - a.
$$
Moreover, by definition,
$$
ab \leq \varphi^*(a) + \varphi(b),
\qquad
\forall a>0, b\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

Comment: Are there any other approaches?

Comment: You need not know that this stuff is related to "Fenchel transform". Just estimate $ab - e^b \leq \sup_{b\in\mathbb{R}} (ab - e^b) = a\log a - a$.

Comment: Ok, thanks! @Rigel